Why doesn't SIM800 modem register to the cellular network?
SIM800 doesn't register/connect to a cellular modem.
It was able to register for two days, but now it can't for some reason.
I can see the correct network when sending AT+COPS=? to the modem.
I tried to reset the modem but the problem persist.
What might be the reason?
ATI
SIM800 R14.18

OK
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CFUN?
+CFUN: 1

OK
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0

OK
AT+COPS=?
+COPS: (2,"Telecom","Telecom","22402"),(3,"Telecom1","Telecom1","22401"),,(0-4),(0-2)

OK
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 12,0

OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,0

OK
at+creg=1
OK
at+creg?
+CREG: 1,0

OK
at+cops?
+COPS: 0

Update:
at+cfun=0
+CPIN: NOT READY

OK
at+cfun=1
+CREG: 2

+CPIN: READY

OK

SMS Ready

Call Ready

+CREG: 3

+CREG: 0

for some reason I get +CREG: 3 from at+cfun=1:
CREG 2 = not registered, but MT is currently searching a new operator to register to
CREG 3 = registration denied

What might be the reason that the registration was denied? It was working fine for two days.

Did your carrier perhaps shut down their 2G GSM/GPRS service?

@grawity_u1686 was working for two days, 2g is still supported in my country.

"registration denied" => call your network operator.
